# Payara does not start from Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish, payara

The Payara with GlassFish 5.192.0 does not start using the Intellij Idea.

If I run payara\bin\asadmin start-domain is works just fine, and the server starts and runs.

These are the final lines from the console output with the --verbose property set on true.

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
Command start-domain failed.
The DAS was stopped.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root case of the issue is [logged here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218032).

Windows launcher prepends `PATH` with JetBrains Runtime `bin` directory in order to load certain DLLs without issues. It turned out to be not the best solution and we are working to address it in a different way.

`asadmin.bat` uses the first `java.exe` from `PATH`. It doesn't try to detect it via `JAVA_HOME`.

The workaround for now is to switch IntelliJ IDEA boot JDK to JBR8 per [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879) or start IntelliJ IDEA using `idea.bat` instead of `idea64.exe`.

The issue is fixed in [2019.2.1 RC](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2019.2+EAP).